# Buttons not responding when pressing

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm new to android development and I'm making a simple calculator. Everything is working fine and no errors are showing but `Buttons` aren't working whenever I press them.

My target SDK is `API 19: Android 4.4(Kitkat)` and compiling with `API 20: Android 4.4(KitKat Wear)`. Here is my code,

**MainActivity.java**

```
package edu.shihank.mycalcv2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public TextView tv;
public float numbBf;
public String Operation;
public ButtonClickListener btnClick;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    int idList[] = {R.id.zero, R.id.one, R.id.two, R.id.three, R.id.four,
            R.id.five, R.id.six, R.id.seven, R.id.eight, R.id.nine, R.id.add,
            R.id.sub, R.id.div, R.id.multi, R.id.equal, R.id.clear, R.id.history};

    for(int id:idList){
        View v = (View)findViewById(id);
        v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void getKeyboard(String str) {
    String tvNow = tv.getText().toString();
    tvNow += str;
    tv.setText(tvNow);
}

public void theResult() {
    float numbAf = Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
    float result = 0;
    if(Operation.equals("+")){
        result = numbAf + numbBf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("-")){
        result = numbAf - numbBf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("*")){
        result = numbAf * numbBf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("/")){
        result = numbAf / numbBf;
    }
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}

public void theMath(String str) {
    numbBf = Float.parseFloat(tv.getText().toString());
    Operation = str;
    tv.setText("0");
}

private class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.clear:
            tv.setText("0");
            numbBf = 0;
            Operation = "";
            break;
        case R.id.add:
            theMath("+");
            break;
        case R.id.sub:
            theMath("-");
            break;
        case R.id.div:
            theMath("/");
            break;
        case R.id.multi:
            theMath("*");
            break;
        case R.id.equal:
            theResult();
            break;
        default:
            String numb = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
            getKeyboard(numb);
            break;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Too much unessessary code! reduce your code to a minimal version reproducing your problem! See: http://sscce.org/

Comment: As mentioned by haywire, there is certainly too much code here. In the future, try to cut it down to the minimum *you think* we need to start. We can always kindly ask for more if needed. I have removed the unnecessary code for you as it is likely to attract downvotes and possibly close votes for you. It also makes the question more manageable to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

btnClick has not been initialized! Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    int idList[] = {R.id.zero, R.id.one, R.id.two, R.id.three, R.id.four,
        R.id.five, R.id.six, R.id.seven, R.id.eight, R.id.nine, R.id.add,
        R.id.sub, R.id.div, R.id.multi, R.id.equal, R.id.clear, R.id.history};

     btnClick = new ButtonClickListener(); // add this line

     for(int id:idList){
        View v = (View)findViewById(id);
        v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's working now but now a new problem raised. If I use any operation(+, -, /, *) my app gets `force close`. Any idea why?

Comment: we are not here to debug your code. your original question has been answered. if your have another well researched question then create a new thread!

Comment: ok, I'll try the other prob. And given your ans the right. Tnx a lot. :)

Comment: my pleasure and feel free to ask more questions, but please, like I said, do reserach/debugging first. then you can make a new thread if you are stuck again. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you have `btnClick` initialized anywhere. You should have something like

```
btnClick = new ButtonClickListener();
```

somewhere **before** setting the listeners.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate an instance of your listener, currently it's null:

```
btnClick = new ButtonClickListener();
```

Answer (score 1):

Above is the correct answer, but you don't need to create a new ButtonClickListener that extends the OnClickListener if you aren't drastically modifying the class. Here's an alternative approach

```
private OnClickListener btnCLick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public onClick(View v) {
        // Switch statement here
    }
}
```

And now you don't actually need to declare `btnClick = new ButtonClickListener()`. And just for fun, another way is your main activity class can `implement View.OnClickListner` and then set `button.setOnClickListener(this);`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Other stuff
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Switch statement here
    }
}
```

Just to show you all of the possible ways to solve the problem. I prefer to implement the listener on the class so you're not storing a variable, but do whatever works best for your case.

Comment: Tnx. I'll try that after I finish my project. :)